# When I'll be able to ask question?

Tags: discussion

I see this message

## You have reached your question limit

*Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.*

When this will resolve.
Even though my previous question was down voted because of formatting and it's voted up as I asked in meta why so down voted and I get respond there not only with votes up but comments also. So now why I'm facing **"You have reached your question limit**"?  I don't think I've to clear my any previous question to resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't see how you could be question banned on Superuser.  You don't have any visible questions with a negative score. You just have to wait (time wise) since your asking to many questions to quickly

Comment: Please see [this MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295684) (it's very helpful and has a lot of relevant links). I believe the block is of indefinite length; you will need to repair your existing questions before you can ask again. If you have deleted questions, it's likely that those are the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound "visible" being the problem. 10 questions, 6 deleted, sum of scores -2 (+3/-5).

Comment: @BenN All SE question bans allow a single question to be asked after 6 months.  But unless the quality of the questions improve that question won't be well received either

Comment: Disadvantage of SE is people votes down without let know what is wrong with it. I asked on meta why down voted and then someone edited and then I could get better respond there. I had commented why so but just voting down.

Comment: Instead of putting energies into complaints about the community you should be spending your energy to improve your questions quality

Comment: I can't find any Superuser questions of yours that have been edited incorrectly.  This meta website only covers Superuser

Answer (score 1):

Its worth considering the underlying problem so far - that the quality of your questions so far have not been that good. The ones that have had some degree of acceptance by the community don't outweigh the ones that are deleted.

Word is by fixing your questions and contributing productively, through quality posts and edits, you could get out of a question ban. I would emphasise *quality*. Farming crappy posts and edits may end up working against you. You'd want to focus on *exceptional* and very substantial edits, and deep, interesting answers.

Looking at those questions, it also feels like there's some confusion to what the scope of our site is - and some oneliners that need a lot of love to work

There's no 'easy' solution to this